# git rebase --onto crashes only on long branches

Tags: git, crash, rebase

I'm having problems to make a simple `git rebase` (no conflicts involved) when the rebased branch has too many commits. I couldn't find a similar error on stackoverflow neither on google.

I've found the problem trying to rebase a long branch (really?) with 71 commits:

```
$ git clone git@myrepo.com/project.git
$ cd project
$ git checkout develop
$ vim README.md # just a simple text update on tracked file
$ git add README.md
$ git commit -m "crash test"
$ git checkout feature/branch-to-be-rebased
$ git rebase --onto develop feature/big-branch-to-be-rebased~71

First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: commit 01
Applying: commit 02
Applying: commit 03
...
Applying: commit 20
Assertion failed: (postlen ? fixed_preimage.nr == preimage->nr : fixed_preimage.nr <= preimage->nr), function update_pre_post_images, file apply.c, line 2322.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--am: line 16: 44878 Abort trap: 6           git am $git_am_opt --rebasing --resolvemsg="$resolvemsg" ${gpg_sign_opt:+"$gpg_sign_opt"} < "$GIT_DIR/rebased-patches"
```

`git rebase` is working properly when the branch is short (it worked on 8 commits branch).

My OS is a `Sierra 10.12.6`

```
$ git --version
git version 2.13.6 (Apple Git-96)
```

Same thing happened using up to date brew's git version:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.15.0/bin/git --version
git version 2.15.0
```

I know some people will have different opinions about git workflow, but the point of this question is purely technical. So I'm not interested on workarounds like squash, cherry-pick, etc.

Is there a way to fix this crash? Does `git rebase` have some sort of upper limit on the number of commits it can handle? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to fix this crash?

Repair the bug in Git, of course.  (You said you are not interested in workarounds, but this appears to come from having `--whitespace=fix` as a command line argument, or setting `apply.whitespace=fix` in your configuration.  Eliminating that will probably sidestep the problem.)

> Does git rebase have some sort of upper limit on the number of commits it can handle?

No.

> Is this a known bug?

Well, it is now. :-)  Without a good reproducer, though, I'm not sure if anyone *else* can fix it.  (So perhaps this depends on what you mean by "known bug": your example shows that there is a bug in the whitespace-fixing code, but it's not clear what the bug is, yet.)

Comment: Indeed I had (for a very long time) 

    [apply]
    whitespace = fix

on my `~/.gitconfigure`. It was just a matter of getting rid of this line

Thanks! It worked